# How to use PYTHONBREAKPOINT to start ipython?

Tags: python, ipython, ipdb

I was trying to get the interactive ipython which can also make use of auto-complete by doing the following but somehow I see it starting ipdb instead and not being able to make use of auto-complete.

```sh
pip install ipython pyreadline
export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=IPython.core.debugger.set_trace
# add breakpoint() somewhere inside the code

python whatever.py
```

The result is that ipdb is started, and pressing TAB will not do any auto-completes.

```
ipdb>
```

In fact the outcome looks the same as doing `export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace` which is quite weird.

If I start ipython manually it works fine and auto-complete works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Python/IPython/IPDB do you have? Where are you running them?

It's hard to know without additional context, but I do know that even when fully functioning, hitting `TAB` when the cursor is in the first position on the command line in either IPython or IPDB will indent, not tab complete, ***even if there are other characters present***.

If you type `dis` and then `TAB`, you should see something like the following:

[image: tab-completion]

There are other possibilities. I've seen things get weird, for example, if one's `TERM` is set to something simple or esoteric (see, e.g., `TERM=ansi` or `TERM=rxvt`), if one doesn't have a fully-functional terminal to begin with, if one redirects/messes with STDIN/STDOUT (or has other tools interacting with those; see, e.g., [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13104) where IPython/IPDB have weird interactions with `python -m doctest`), etc.

I've also seen disparities between when `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` is set to `ipdb.sset_trace` or `ipdb.set_trace` (tab completion works) and when it's set to `IPython.core.debugger.set_trace` (behaves like a dumb terminal).

Comment: adding ipdb to my requirements.txt and exporting `PYTHONBREAKPOINT='ipdb.set_trace'` works for me

Answer (score 0):

In short, use : `export PYTHONBREAKPOINT='IPython.terminal.debugger.set_trace'`
Tested on IPython v8.19.0

From the [docstring of Ipython.core.debugger](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/main/IPython/core/debugger.py) module we can read:

> This is an extension to PDB which adds a number of new features.
> Note that there is also the `IPython.terminal.debugger` class which provides UI improvements.

`core.debugger` doesn't seem to be officially deprecated though, I guess internally in ipython it has some uses.

There is also the [ipdb](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/tree/master) package that is meant to improve the experience of using the Ipython debugger, but it is maintained independently from Ipython and I haven't tried it yet.